# How to execute ascii code if val == ascii code do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii

I want to append links to contextmenu when right click i disabled the right click menu. Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="menu">
      <a href="#" id="f12" value="123" onclick="return false;">inspect element</a>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
      $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){

        $('#menu').css({
            top: e.pageY+'px',
            left: e.pageX+'px'
        }).show();

        $(document).click(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
        });

        return false;
      });
    $('#do').on("click", function(e){
    var n = $('#do').val();
     if(n == 123){}
     e.keyCode; // i want to show inspector (console) 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `I want to append links to contextmenu when right click i disabled the right click menu` that is already happening, what is the problem?

Comment: What does "execute ASCII code" mean? Mouse clicks don't have an ASCII code. Are you trying to ask how to open the browser's development console from JS, and you think you could do that by simulating a press of the F12 key?

Comment: I want to append to append functions to context after searching i see this impossible so i wanna to make it

I know mouse click don't have an ASCII code but i want execute it if value = 123 (f12) same like press f12